# WebClient GET request doesn't seem to do anything in C#

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio, http

I created a simple PHP script that adds lines to a text file.
When I type the url into the browser, it adds to the text file just fine.
However, something seemingly simple to do in C# does not seem to work. When I run this code in a windows forms application, nothing gets added to the text file

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.QueryString.Add("name", "one");
webClient.QueryString.Add("status", "off");
string result = webClient.DownloadString("http://example.com/submit.php?");
```

I have also tried just doing:

```
webClient.DownloadString("http://example.com/submit.php?name=one&status=off");
```

I've browsed countless posts and tried the httpgetrequest as well. Nothing seems to add a line of text to my file.

Here is my output console:

```
'CSHARP.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: CSHARP.exe): Loaded 

'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("1aced16c4a6991033825473de09075a3");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://example.com/submit.php?name=one&status=off&i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
'CSHARP.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: CSHARP.exe): Loaded 'D:\Drive\WORK\CSHARP\CSHARP\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

Comment: So have you used a tool like fiddler to see the request and response both from your borwser/postman/C#

Comment: @MichaelRandall I've never used fiddler, but upon inspection under the "web forms" tab, it shows under key that there are two entries, one for name and one for status. This leads me to believe that it's fine I suppose, and maybe something with php. However, why would it work when typing it into the browser? This leads me to believe it has something to do with the url encoding. Thoughts?

Comment: The console output says : "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support".  I think you need to add a user agent header to your webclient so the server knows you have a java supported request.  See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent